# A layer above UIView to show messages in UIAlertView style?

Tags: objective-c

Maybe my question was already addressed here, but i didn't know how to search for it .
We need to have some window which is above a view , to show some messages similar to `UIAlertView` that is not covering all screen.

Drawing just some rect with text is easy, but i want to create some container subview, that i can just load into it view(which has his a `viewController` class), and preferred with `storyboard`.

Is there something out of the box at `Xcode`,or do i need to create it on my own ?

Edit:
I have tried that, it worked, but if i load into it some other view controller, its going out from the UIWindow bounds, so even that the UIWindow is at width 200, the view i load into it is cover almost all screen , why is that ?

```
UIViewController *inner=  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signUpView" ];
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 200)];
backgroundWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
[backgroundWindow addSubview:inner.view];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundWindow];
```

Comment: You can use [`UIWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) to present you view

Comment: thanks , you gave me a quite general answer , how do i use it to my needs with storyboard ?

Comment: I gave a general answer because I have no idea about how to use it with storyboards. Also if you google there are many examples out there.

Comment: ok , thanks, see my edit please, i have managed to do it with sotryboard but i have some strange problem with it

Comment: You will need to make the `UIWindow` as big as the screen, Windows on iOS are always presented fullscreen.

Comment: I dont understand you. as i said in my question , i need to show a view which is smaller than the device window ,

Comment: The View you place on the window can be smaller, but the window should be fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks,but its not relevant to my question at all.

Comment: Well you can still do what you want, just look at the source of [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) it use a `UIWindow` and still allowing user interaction.